# Is every Hilbert space a Banach algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Could we say that, always there is a multiplication on $H$, that makes it into a Banach algebra? If not, under which conditions does it exist?

Comment: Is it not true if you choose the multiplication as xy=0 for all x,y in the Hilbert space?

Comment: I think it is true. But I ask my question for non-trivial multiplication

Comment: Well, suppose that  $H=\ell^2$. Then I think it is Banach algebra with pointwise multiplication.

Comment: @Hamid And I think this is valid for all separable Hilbert spaces with infinite dimension since they are isometric isomorph to $l^2$.

Comment: Yeah! Every separable Hilbert space is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^2$.~~~~~~~
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space

Comment: @Hamid: No problem about non-separable spaces: $\#S=\dim\mathcal{H}:\mathcal{H}\cong\ell^2(S)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $J $ be an index for the cardinality of an orthonormal basis of $H $. Then $H $ is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^2 (J) $, so it is enough to discuss the problem on this latter space.

Define the product $fg $ pointwise, i.e. $fg (j):=f (j)g (j) $. The question is whether this product stays in $\ell^2$, and whether the norm is submultiplicative. We have
$$
\|fg\|_2^2=\sum_j|f (j)|^2\,|g (j)|^2\leq\|f\|_\infty^2\,\|g\|_2^2\leq\|f\|_2^2\,\|g\|_2^2,
$$
so the two norm and the pointwise product make $\ell^2$ a Banach algebra.

Comment: Nice! So every Hilbert space can be turned into a Banach algebra? _(Even C*-algebra?)_

Comment: Only for **separable** Hilbert spaces it is true!

Comment: @Freeze_S: Yes, not that it is useful. C$^*$-algebra is a different matter, as you need an involution that satisfies the C$^*$-identity. The above product will make a Hilbert space a C$^*$-algebra only when the dimension is one. I don't know how to create other norms in which $H$ is complete.

Comment: @user51514: why? What fails in a non-separable Hilbert space?

Comment: Yes but as you introduced a multiplication $(\varphi\psi)(x):=\varphi(x)\psi(x)$one might as well try an involition, suggestively $(\varphi^*)(x):=\overline{\varphi(x)}$.

Comment: @Freeze_S:  as I already said, you still need a norm in which that involution satisfies the C$^*$-identity, and that makes $H$ complete. I cannot imagine what that would be.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Aaah yes the one you used won't be good enough..

Comment: An infinite-dimensional C*-algebra is never reflexive so it cannot be Banach-space isomorphic to a Hilbert space! The quickest way to see this is to take a self-adjoint element $t$ with infinite spectrum and apply the spectral theorem to it getting a subalgebra isometric to $C_0(S)$.

Comment: @user51514 separability doesn't matter here.

Comment: @TomekKania: you say  for any Hilbert space $H$, there is a index set $J$, that $H\cong\ell^2(J)$ (isometric isomorphism)? I thought this is true for only separable Hilbert space.

Comment: @user51514, yes that's true. This is essentially Parseval's identity.

Comment: Could you please introduce a book for its proof? Thanks

Comment: It is certainly done with some care in Conway's "A Course in Functional Analysis".

Answer (score 4):

Another Banach-algebra structure on the Hilbert space $\mathsf{hs}(H)$ of Hilbert-Schmidt operators on a Hilbert space $H$ is just operator multiplication (composition). There is a natural involution on this algebra but it does not make it a C*-algebra.